# Spring cloud stream kafka transaction configuration

Tags: transactions, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I am following [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-stream-kafka-avro-confluent) template for `Spring-cloud-stream-kafka` but got stuck while making the producer method `transactional`. I have not used `kafka` earlier so need help with this in case any configuration changes needed in `kafka`

It works well if no transactional configuration added but when transactional configurations are added it **gets timed out at startup** -

```
2020-11-21 15:07:55.349 ERROR 20432 --- [           main] o.s.c.s.b.k.p.KafkaTopicProvisioner      : Failed to obtain partition information
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timeout expired after 60000milliseconds while awaiting InitProducerId
```

below is my setup for Spring-cloud-stream

**pom.xml**

```
<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
    <spring-boot.version>2.3.3.RELEASE</spring-boot.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR8</spring-cloud.version>
    <kafka-avro-serializer.version>5.2.1</kafka-avro-serializer.version>
    <avro.version>1.8.2</avro.version>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
          <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
          <type>pom</type>
          <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

**transactionManager**

```
@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(BinderFactory binders) {
    ProducerFactory<byte[], byte[]> pf = ((KafkaMessageChannelBinder) binders.getBinder("kafka",
            MessageChannel.class)).getTransactionalProducerFactory();
    return new KafkaTransactionManager<>(pf);
}
```

**application.yml**

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      default: 
         producer: 
          useNativeEncoding: true
         consumer:  
          useNativeEncoding: true     
      bindings:
        input:
          destination: employee-details
          content-type: application/*+avro
          group: group-1
          concurrency: 3
        output:
          destination: employee-details
          content-type: application/*+avro
      kafka:
          binder:        
           producer-properties:
             key.serializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer
             value.serializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer
             schema.registry.url: http://localhost:8081
             acks: all
             max.block.ms: 60000             
           consumer-properties:
             key.deserializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer
             value.deserializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer
             schema.registry.url: http://localhost:8081
             specific.avro.reader: true
           transaction:
            transactionIdPrefix: tx-
           producer:
             enable:
               idempotence: true
#             requiredAcks: all
           brokers:
           - localhost:9094
```

I am running `kafka` in `minikube`, below is config for my topic

```
[2020-11-21 06:18:21,655] INFO [ZooKeeperClient] Connected. (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient)
Topic: employee-details PartitionCount: 1       ReplicationFactor: 1    Configs:
        Topic: employee-details Partition: 0    Leader: 0       Replicas: 0     Isr: 0
```

**logs from kafka controller**

```
TRACE [Controller id=0] Checking need to trigger auto leader balancing (kafka.controller.KafkaController)
[2020-11-24 06:56:21,379] DEBUG [Controller id=0] Topics not in preferred replica for broker 0 Map() (kafka.controller.KafkaController)
[2020-11-24 06:56:21,379] TRACE [Controller id=0] Leader imbalance ratio for broker 0 is 0.0 (kafka.controller.KafkaController)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the server log.

Transactional producers will time out if there are fewer replicas of the transaction state log than required. By default 3 replicas are required and a minimum of 2 need to be in sync.

See
`transaction.state.log.replication.factor` and `transaction.state.log.min.isr`.

Comment: thanks for the response. But I have already mentioned `ReplicationFactor: 1` and `Isr: 0` in the question above. is that not correct?

Comment: That information is about the topic; those properties in the log are simply saying that your topic is on broker zero and it has a single ISR (also broker 0).  the properties I mentioned are broker properties and need to be configured there. The properties are for the transaction log topic and by default it needs 3 replicas and 2 isrs.

Comment: thanks managed to change these broker properties. Transaction flow works now.

Comment: @AmitNaik Do you remember what you set those 2 parameters (replication.factor and min.isr) to? I tried 1/1 and 3/2 without luck.